# Can brain cells move?

Tags: cell-biology, neuroscience, brain, development, stem-cells

I was discussing this with my brother. I'm pretty sure I read somewhere that they can move.

Thanks

EDIT: By movement I mean long distance migration (preferably within the brain only).

Comment: If I recall correctly, there is neuronal migration during embryonic development? If you have a better wording for this, tell me so I can edit my Q. Thanks.

Comment: Do you consider the cells of a malignant brain tumor "brain cells"? Because they do move when invading the tissue.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The question is relatively broad and one should take into account that the brain not only consists of *neurons*, but also *glial cells* (supportive cells) and *pre-mitotic neuronal stem cells*. Furthermore, as critical fellow-scientists have indicated, developmental stage is very important, as the developing embryonic brain is very different from the adult brain.

However, after sifting through various publications, the answer to the question is actually remarkably simple: **Yes, brain cells migrate.**

In  the **adult brain** glial cells migrate in the brain ([Klämbt, 2009](http://www.nature.com/nrn/journal/v10/n11/abs/nrn2720.html)). Glial cells are involved in a myriad of functions, but a notable example of migrating glial cells are the oligodendrocytes that migrate relative long distances to find their target axons onto which they wrap themselves to form the insulating myelin sheath ([Tsai and Miller, 2002](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166223600020968)).

Neuronal stem cells migrate over long distances in response to injury ([Imitola et al., 2004](http://www.pnas.org/content/101/52/18117.full.pdf+html)) and they migrate from specific stem-cell locations (e.g., hippocampus and subventricular zone) to other regions ([Clarke, 2003](http://www.nature.com/bmt/journal/v32/n1s/full/1703937a.html)).

Post-mitotic, but non-differentiated neurons have been shown to migrate in the adult brain in fish ([Scott et al., 2012](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/32/4/1436.full)), and in mammals and non-human primates as well ([Sawada et al., 2011](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/284133696_Neuronal_Migration_in_the_Adult_Brain)).

Not surprisingly, glial cells, stem cells and neurons also migrate during **embryonic development**. Most notably, post-mitotic neurons destined to fulfill peripheral functions have to migrate over relatively long distances from the neural crest to their target locations ([Neuroscience, 2<sup>nd</sup> ed, Neuronal Migration](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10831/)).

Comment: Great answer. Glial cells (resident, supporting cells) also include resident immune cells, such as microglia, which are related to the monocyte lineage

Comment: "oligodendrocytes ... wrap themselves to form the insulting myelin sheath" - wait, what? TIL.

Comment: Not only that, I didn't know the myelin sheath is formed by having some extra cells migrate into place. I thought they were acellular and grew from the axon?

Comment: Yep, they are definitely cellular - follow the citing link, grab any neuroscience textbook, or everyone's best pal wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myelin. Thanks for the typo though :)

Answer (score 11):

To add to Christiaan's answer, I'll mention one striking example of long-distance neuronal migration in the adult mammalian brain: the so-called **[Rostral Migratory Stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rostral_migratory_stream)** found in rodents, in rabbits and both the squirrel and rhesus monkey.

Neuronal precursors originating in the subventricular zone (SVZ) of the brain migrate to reach the main olfactory bulb (OB), and it's quite a distance for the small cells.

[image]